# Controlling number of characters in expression?

Tags: regex

Can I somehow limit the number of characters of this whole expression?

I want to limit number of characters in an expression like:

```
([0-9]+(\.?[0-9]+)*)
```

I want the strings following the limit to be accepted.  For 
example, if the limit is 4:

- `12.3` gets accepted
- `012` doesn't
- `12345` doesn't.

Comment: Why 012 not? It's  within the limit of 4. Or it is not a limit, but a specified length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an anchored look ahead (for example max 33):

```
^(?=.{0,33}$)([0-9]+(\.?[0-9]+)*)
```

To make it *exactly* 33, remove the `0,`

---

To ignore the number of periods in the limit

```
^(?=(\.*[^.]){0,33}\.*$)([0-9]+(\.?[0-9]+)*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,another quickie,Can I somehow make it ignore the number of periods?

Comment: @poncha See edit for bonus answer on how to ignore periods in the limit

Comment: @Bohemian with the second one, the limit doesnt really work. try changing it to {4} and run on the input... 12345 is a match.

Answer (score 1):

Regex quantifiers:

- `{n}` - Exactly `n` appearances
- `{n,m}` - Minimum `n` occurences, maximum `m` occurences
- `{,m}` - Minimum zero, maximum `m`
- `{n,}` - Minimum `n`, maximum infinity.
- `*` - Any amount. Equivalent to `{0,}`
- `+` - One or more. Equivalent to `{1,}`
- `?` - zero or one. Exuivalent to `{0,1}`

This about sums it up.

Comment: I'm keeping this answer as a general reference on the quantifiers, but the real answer to this question is [the one provided by @Bohemian](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18203766/620813).